# Unable to show custom Dialog with progressbar

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using custom layout for my Dialog to show progress bar and text.The layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/popuplayout"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressdialog" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressmsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="loading..." />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and assigning this layout in dialog through a method in my util.java(not a activity) like

```
private static Dialog progressDialog = null;
public static void showLoadingProgress(String msg){
        Log.d("EditorUtil", "show loading progress"+progressDialog);//No i18n

        progressDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.getActivity());
        progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.customprogress);

        TextView message = (TextView)progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressmsg);
        message.setText(msg);

        progressDialog.show();
        Log.d("",progressDialog.isShowing()+""); //No i18n
    }
```

While calling this method, am unable to see the dialog but the logs are printing properly. please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Custom Dialog

If you want a customized design for a dialog, you can create your own layout for the dialog window with layout and widget elements. After you've defined your layout, pass the root View object or layout resource ID to setContentView(View).

```
For example, to create the dialog shown to the right:

Create an XML layout saved as custom_dialog.xml:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
               />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

This XML defines an ImageView and a TextView inside a LinearLayout. Set the above layout as the dialog's content view and define the content for the ImageView and TextView elements:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View dialogRoot = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sync_bars, null);
cancelDialog.setView(dialogRoot);
ProgressBar hbar = (ProgressBar) dialogRoot.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

you have to reference to your progress bar to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what may be the reason behind you problem but I can suggest few things that you may find helpful

1. Use the context instead of the getActivity.

   progressDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.getActivity());

should be replaced with context that you must add to your util class and should be passed    through constructor

```
 progressDialog = new Dialog(context);
```

I hope you are not passing the object of Activity through getActivity method.

1. Instead of using the progressDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND); and 
   progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

you can add all such stuff to the R.style.Your theme

3.If create a seperate class for the dialog extending the Dialog class like this

```
public class TextEditDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
            Button cancelButton;
            public Button okBtn;
            TextView title;
            EditText nameField,password;
            public static long id;
            public static int code;
            CheckBox rememberme;
            Context c;
            TableRow bottomoftextdialog;
            TextView bottomtexttochange,toptexttochange;

            public TextEditDialog(Context context) {
                super(context,R.style.Theme_Custom);
                c=context;
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Uname);
                password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                rememberme=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.rememberme);
                okBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
                bottomoftextdialog=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.bottomoftextdialog);

                bottomtexttochange=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.bottomtexttochange);
                toptexttochange=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.toptexttochange);
                okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }

    this way you will be able to manage things really well.
```